# Giving generated random raster same extent and coordinate system of input raster in ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, coordinate-system, modelbuilder, extents

In ArcGIS's (10.1, advanced license) ModelBuilder, I want to create a random raster (let's call it **B**) with values between 0.90 and 1.0, and I want to multiply another raster (let's call it **A**) by **B**. **A** is fed into the model by the user. *My goal*: I want **B** to have the same extent and coordinate system as **A**. What I think to do to accomplish the first goal is to drag and drop the CREATE RANDOM RASTER tool into the ModelBuilder and then using the tool's drop-down menu "output extent" to select raster **A**. I *do not know* how to proceed about the second goal, namely selecting for raster **B** the same coordinate system as **A**. I have added a picture portraying an illustrative example of the model.
[image]

Comment: What does your model so far look like in a picture?

Comment: Well, I haven't created an actual model yet. I am simply trying to envisage what the viable option would be for that problem.

Comment: As a potential answerer of your question I know that I would visualise model elements much more easily than bolded letters.

Comment: I have edited my question, adding a picture.

Comment: If the extent of A is to set the extent of B then I think it will be easiest to connect into a tool prior to the creation of B by Create Random Raster.

Comment: The extent and coordinate system of B should be the same as A.

Comment: So what's the extent and coordinate system of B prior to A joining the model?

Comment: Apologies, maybe I am not managing to make my point clearer. Raster A is what I have. I feed it into the model. What the model should do is to create the random raster (B), and to multiply A by B. Therefore (correct me if I am wrong) B must have the same extent and coord syst as A. That's why I want the model to get the extent and coord syst of A and "apply" them to B before performing RASTER CALCULATOR.